# Google drive API update permissions

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am trying to change ownership of a file in Google Drive using the following call:

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/XXXXXX/permissions/YYYYY?transferOwnership=true&useDomainAdminAccess=true
{
    "kind": "drive#permission",
    "role": "owner"
}
```

However, I get this in return:

```
{
    "error": {
    "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "notFound",
            "message": "Team Drive not found: XXXXXX",
            "locationType": "parameter",
            "location": "teamDriveId"
        }
    ],
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Team Drive not found: XXXXXX"
    }
}
```

XXXXXX is definitely a file that exists. The problem still happens with `supportsTeamDrives=false`.

Comment: Have you tried setting it to supportsTeamDrives to true? Tried this on Permissions.list and noticed that if supportsTeamDrives is set to false, the file cannot be accessed.

Comment: I've the same question, I tried with supportsTeamDrives=true and it gave me the same error.